# By just looking at the time period of the oscillation, can we know whether the motion is simple harmonic or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators

My questions are:

(1) By just looking at the time period of the oscillation, can we know whether the motion is simple harmonic or not? How?

(2) Is the same true for angular (circular) SHM?